# Multi instance - MYSQL/PHPmyAdmin - WINDOWS Server

Tags: mysql, windows, binding, mysql-8.0

I have 2 Windows Server with Mysql/phpmyadmin.
One is my current server with production, the other will be use to save and backup the production (With a replication D-1 and D-7)

There is no problem on my production.

On Replication, i need to bind multiple adress in my.ini
When i've installed 2 instances of Mysql, i've tried 2 ways to separate the instances.

I change the port without binding ip, and it works.

If i put bind-address, i've got an error.

My services are UP and works
I already put the second IP address on the Ethernet Advanced TCP/IP configuration.

I'm blocked cause i don't know why the binding address didn't work

Thank you !

I change the port without binding ip, and it works
Connection on PHPmyadmin and MYSQL Command line

Ex my.ini D-1 :

```
[client]
no-beep

port=3306

[mysqld]
# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on


port=3306
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\

# Path to the database root
datadir=D:\MySQLDatafiles\
```

myd7.ini D-7 :

```
[client]
no-beep

port=3307

[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3307
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0j4

# Path to the database root
datadir=D:\MySQLDatafilesJ4

But when i put bind-address, Mysql Instance failed.

[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
bind-address=111.11.11.111
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0j4

[mysqld]

# The TCP/IP Port the MySQL Server will listen on
port=3306
bind-address=111.11.11.222
# Path to installation directory. All paths are usually resolved relative to this.
basedir=C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0j4
```

Here are the error :
Connection on phpmyadmin

```
mysqli::real_connect(): (HY000/2002):
No connection could be established because the target computer expressly refused it
```

Connection with mysql.exe with command line :

```
C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql 111.11.11.111 -u root -p
Enter password: *********
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)

C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin>mysql 111.11.11.222 -u root -p
Enter password: *********
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on 'localhost:3306' (10061)
```

I'm available if you need more information !

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply !

It works thank you, after many and many hours, i was blinded by it but i just need to specifiate Port with the right IP in the my.ini file !

111.11.11.111 with port 3306
and 111.11.11.222 with port 3307.